# Android app stores high score value as int in sharedpreferences. The app throws an outofbounds exception if a score over 100 is reached

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, box2d, andengine

I  have an Android game that uses the SharedPreferences to store the high score for the game on the device. This works perfectly well until the high score on the device exceeds 100 points at which time it causes the app to crash the next time it gets the int from the SharedPreferences. Here is the code related to storing and retrieving the score from SharedPreferences.

```
public void setHighScore(int score) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor settingsEditor = prefs.edit();
    settingsEditor.putInt(Constants.KEY_HIGHSCORE, score);
    settingsEditor.commit();
    }

public int getHighScore() {
    return prefs.getInt(Constants.KEY_HIGHSCORE, 0);
}  



if (score > activity.getHighScore()) {
    activity.setHighScore(score);
}

        yourScoreText.setText("Your Score: " + score);
        yourScoreText.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        yourScoreText.setVisible(true);

        highScoreText.setText("High Score: " + activity.getHighScore());
        highScoreText.setColor(Color.RED);
        highScoreText.setVisible(true);
```

Logcat

```
09-19 22:00:13.612: W/dalvikvm(26458): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417a9898)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=360; index=360
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.entity.text.vbo.HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject.onUpdateVertices(HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject.java:124)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.entity.text.Text.onUpdateVertices(Text.java:333)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.entity.shape.Shape.setSize(Shape.java:146)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.entity.text.Text.setText(Text.java:221)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at hungryfish.scene.GameScene.reset(GameScene.java:246)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at hungryfish.scene.GameScene.onSceneTouchEvent(GameScene.java:308)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene.onSceneTouchEvent(Scene.java:387)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchScene(Engine.java:470)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTouchEvent(Engine.java:456)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController$TouchEventRunnablePoolItem.run(BaseTouchController.java:102)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:54)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.onHandlePoolItem(RunnablePoolUpdateHandler.java:1)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler.onUpdate(PoolUpdateHandler.java:88)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.input.touch.controller.BaseTouchController.onUpdate(BaseTouchController.java:62)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:604)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:57)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:568)
09-19 22:00:13.622: E/AndroidRuntime(26458):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
```

Comment: I'm developing a simple android game and keeping high score same as you. I can keep records over 100 in shared preferences. i think error is somewhere else in your application.

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace. At the moment you haven't told us anything about *how* it crashes. Also, please pay more attention to your code formatting - the indentation is all over the place at the moment.

Comment: I'll keep looking further, but it is strange that it doesn't occur until the score is over 100.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, kinda clipped them out of the source from different areas. I didn't have my device connected to my computer at the time. It took me a long time to get to a score over 100 so the app is actually released in the market. I will see if my other tester has a copy from his crash when he went over 100.

Comment: I added the crash text to the original post.

Comment: @Jul Thanks for fixing the logcat. A little tired at the moment I guess.

Comment: There is no such cause of crash for storing values greater than 100 in shared preference .Your code contain bug somewhere else..

Comment: What happens in line 124 in the HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject?

Comment: This is line 124 in HighPerformanceTextVertexBufferObject          bufferData[bufferDataOffset + 0 * Text.VERTEX_SIZE + Text.VERTEX_INDEX_X] = x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would comment this but since i'm under 50 in score i cant.. A simple solution would be to just store the value in a String. Like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(1);
sp.edit().putString("highScore", String.valueOf(highScore)).apply
```

and when you get it out of the shared preference just do

```
int score = Integer.valueOf(sp.getString("highScore", "0"));
```

Personally i'm not a huge fan of shared preferences and instead opt for a sqlite database. The read / write sequences are so much faster when using a database..

One thing you might try is using .apply instead of .commit - .apply runs in the background..

As you asked, i'm providing some code i wrote to help you with your database. I just wrote it and tried it so i know that it works or at least worked on my GS3 (4.4.4) and my OnePlus one (4.4.4).

I would create the classes in separate files but its up-to you. For the example i just used them in my default activity and ran some set / get score code in the onCreate.

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

     //final static stuff because you'll want to access it(the data) in other classes.
     public static final String DB_NAME = "scores.db";
     public static final String SCORE_TABLE = "scores";
     public static final int VERSION = 3;
     private Context context;

     public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
         super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
         this.context = context;
     }

     public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
         return getWritableDatabase();
     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         //our code for creating the ScoreTable..
         db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                 + SCORE_TABLE +
                 "(" +
                 "ID INT NOT NULL, " +
                 "Score INT);");
         //now we create one row of data.
         db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DatabaseHelper.SCORE_TABLE + " (ID, Score) VALUES (1, 0);");
     }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

         //if the version is greater than the previous one, we re-create it.
         if(newVersion > oldVersion) {
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SCORE_TABLE);
             onCreate(db);
         }
     }
 }
public class DataSource{
    //this is a link between your app and the database. you don't have to use this.
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context context;
    private DatabaseHelper helper;
    public DataSource(Context context){
        //initiate our objects.
        this.helper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        this.database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setScore(int score){
        //we update the Score column where the ID is 1
            database.execSQL("UPDATE " + DatabaseHelper.SCORE_TABLE + " SET Score = " + score + " WHERE ID = 1;");
    }
    public int getScore(){
        //we get all of the columns that have a ID of one. There should only be one column.
        Cursor score = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.SCORE_TABLE + " WHERE ID = 1", null);
        //this isn't especially needed, but i found that adding checks and balances keeps crashes down.
        if(score.getColumnCount() < 1){
            return 0;
        } else {
            //this is important! You have to move the cursor to the first row.
            score.moveToFirst();
            //now we get the data on row 1 (actually 2 if you look at it from a 1 based number system..)
            int mscore = score.getInt(1);
            //close the cursor
            score.close();
            //and finally return the score.
            return mscore;
        }
    }

}
```

To use the above code just Create a DataSource object and call the setScore and getScore methods.

Comment: I'll try that and see what happens. If I wanted to change to storing in a sqllite db could you give an example on how to implement it for this case. I only need to store the high score.

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll post a example.

Comment: Thank you. I will work on implementing that to see if it clears up my issue. @Seth would you be at all interested in looking  at the entire source to see if there is something  that I missed on this one?

Comment: I changed to the SQLite DB. I am not sure if I implemented it correctly. Do I need to explicitly call the onCreate method of the DatabaseHelper object?

Comment: I got the DB working in the app. Thanks for that. Unfortunately it didn't solve the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error. It has to be something with the additional character added to the text display. I'm looking into it now. Let me know if you would like to take a look at the full source.

Comment: Finally figured out the issue. `highScoreText = new Text(GameActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - 150, GameActivity.CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 + 0, resourceManager.font, **BOLD"High Score:       ",BOLD** new TextOptions(HorizontalAlign.LEFT), vbom);
  highScoreText.setAnchorCenter(0, 0);
  highScoreText.setText("High Score: 0");`  The part of the constructor in bold was the issue. This specifies the maximum characters in the array apparently. I added a few more spaces before the ending quote and BOOYAH! Fixed! Thanks all for your help. @Seth, thanks for the SQLite help, very handy!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working! How's AndEngine overall? I've been using LibGDX for most of my game development just because of the cross platform capabilities.